# Out of bounds datetime error converting string using pd.to_datetime()

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, datetime

I am unable to convert a string in the format 'YYYYMMDD' to a datetime object due to an error.

```
OutOfBoundsDatetime: Out of bounds nanosecond timestamp: 1-01-01 00:00:00
```

Here is some code snippets I am trying:
[image]

When I try to do:

```
data.move_date = pd.to_datetime(data.move_date)
```

I get the above error. Does anyone know how to fix this? Is this a bug? I did the same exact operation with another column that was in the string format and it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

Adding @COLDSPEED answer

```
data['Dates'] = pd.to_datetime((data.move_data).apply(str),format='%Y%m%d', errors='coerce')
```

Comment: `pd.to_datetime(..., format='%Y%m%d', errors='coerce')`

Comment: @COLDSPEED, that worked thank you! So I'm guessing what we did was ignore all problematic rows. Is there a way to view which rows these are??

Comment: @codebrotherone using`df[pd.to_datetime(..., format='%Y%m%d', errors='coerce') .isnull()]` to search back you original df

Comment: @codebrotherone if the answer helped can you plz upvote the answer plz? :)